# Calculate the area of ​the triangle created by vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$

Tags: vectors

> Given that $\left|\vec{n}\right|=1,\left|\vec{m}\right|=\sqrt{3}$ And that the angle between the vectors $\left|\vec{m}\right|$ and $\left|\vec{n}\right|$ is $30^{\circ }$.
> We will define $\vec{a}\:=\vec{m}\:-\vec{n}\:,\:\vec{b}=\vec{m}+\vec{n}$ calculate the area of ​​the triangle created by vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$.

I found out what $\left|\vec{a}\right|$ and $\left|\vec{b}\right|$ but not sure how to continue form here.

\begin{align}\left|\vec{a}\right|^2&=\left(\vec{m}-\vec{n}\right)\left(\vec{m}-\vec{n}\right)\\
  &=\left|\vec{m}\right|^2-2\vec{m}\cdot\vec{n}+\left|\vec{n}\right|^2\\
&=3-2\sqrt{3}\cdot 1\cdot\:\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+1\\
&=1 \implies \boxed{\left|\vec{a}\right|=1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}\left|\vec{b}\right|^2&=\left(\vec{m}+\vec{n}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{m}+\vec{n}\right)\\
&=\left|\vec{m}\right|^2+2\vec{m}\cdot\vec{n}+\left|\vec{n}\right|^2\\
&=3+2\sqrt{3}\cdot 1\cdot\:\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+1\\
&=7 \implies \boxed{\left|\vec{b}\right|=\sqrt{7}}
\end{align}

Comment: Answer of Nightflight solves the problem, but you can solve it continuing your work: $S=\frac{1}{2} |\vec{a}| |\vec{b}| \sin \angle(\vec{a},\vec{b})=$ $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2-|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2\cos^2 \angle(\vec{a},\vec{b})}=$ $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2-(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2}$. You can easily calculate $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$, then use it in $S$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of triangle generated by $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $ \frac{1}{2} |\vec{u} \times \vec{v}| =  \frac{1}{2} |\vec{u}| |\vec{v}| \sin\theta$.

$ \theta $ is 30 degree.

$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = ( \vec{x} - \vec{y} ) \times ( \vec{x} + \vec{y} ) = \vec{x} \times \vec{x} + \vec{x} \times \vec{y} - \vec{y} \times \vec{x} - \vec{y} \times  \vec{x} = 2\vec{x} \times \vec{y} $

So the area of triangle generated $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is twice of area of triangle generated $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.

So the answer is $ |\vec{x}| |\vec{y}| \sin{$30^{\circ }}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$
.